# Export to "CSV" is not visible in Sales -> Order

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, export-to-excel

I used Magento 1.7.0.2 and in admin -> Sales -> Order, I do not see the button "Export to: CSV". I am trying to figure out where is this button locate. If any developer know this,

Is there a configuration or is there a `<block>` that did not get configure correctly?

please help me. Thank you

Here is the output of `<?php Zend_Debug::dump($this->getExportTypes()) ?>`

```
array(2) {
  [0] => object(Varien_Object)#480 (7) {
    ["_data":protected] => array(2) {
      ["url"] => string(59) "http://192.168.1.24/index.php/admins/sales_order/exportCsv/"
      ["label"] => string(3) "CSV"
    }
    ["_hasDataChanges":protected] => bool(false)
    ["_origData":protected] => NULL
    ["_idFieldName":protected] => NULL
    ["_isDeleted":protected] => bool(false)
    ["_oldFieldsMap":protected] => array(0) {
    }
    ["_syncFieldsMap":protected] => array(0) {
    }
  }
  [1] => object(Varien_Object)#584 (7) {
    ["_data":protected] => array(2) {
      ["url"] => string(61) "http://192.168.1.24/index.php/admins/sales_order/exportExcel/"
      ["label"] => string(9) "Excel XML"
    }
    ["_hasDataChanges":protected] => bool(false)
    ["_origData":protected] => NULL
    ["_idFieldName":protected] => NULL
    ["_isDeleted":protected] => bool(false)
    ["_oldFieldsMap":protected] => array(0) {
    }
    ["_syncFieldsMap":protected] => array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'export to' button is added in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml`, line 98-108:

```
<?php if($this->getExportTypes()): ?>
    <td class="export a-right">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/icon_export.gif') ?>" alt="" class="v-middle"/>&nbsp; <?php echo $this->__('Export to:') ?>
        <select name="<?php echo $this->getId() ?>_export" id="<?php echo $this->getId() ?>_export" style="width:8em;">
        <?php foreach ($this->getExportTypes() as $_type): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $_type->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_type->getLabel() ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <?php echo $this->getExportButtonHtml() ?>
    </td>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Check if you have this code in your file. It should be placed before:

```
<td class="filter-actions a-right">
    <?php echo $this->getMainButtonsHtml() ?>
</td>
```

Also: `$this->getExportTypes()` (line 98) has to return `true` for the export button to appear.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I apologize for the delay. I posted the output of `<?php Zend_Debug::dump($this->getExportTypes()) ?>` in the `grid.phtml` you mention. Please see my post. It looks ok. So it must be the this grid.phtml is being override somewhere else? Can this be remove by `_removeButton()` method?

Comment: Actually, this is a css problem. But thanks you for pointing out the location.